# AWS CloudFormation - Ubuntu Nginx Metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, yaml, metadata, aws-cloudformation

So I am brand new to CloudFormation, and I am trying to create an index.html page using Nginx that displays a line of text, the server's public DNS name, and the AWS region. I'm doing my stack code in YAML. This is part of the code that's under UserData:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nginx
sudo service nginx start
cd /var/www/html
echo "<title>CloudFormation</title><h1>Name</h1><p>This page created entirely by CloudFormation</p>" > index.html
```

I don't know how to pass the metadata into index.html with the echo command. I have tried `!Sub {EC2Instance.PublicDnsName}` which didn't work. Apparently the way is to use the Amazon Metadata Web Service and obtain the values using certain commands then passing them into the index.html but since I am coding in a stack and not using the console I don't know the syntax. Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my code is too long so I cannot post in comment.
I don't use yaml but I can do your expected code in json as below. I use `Fn::Base64` and `Fn::join` syntax. You can reference it and migrate to yaml.

```
"UserData": {
  "Fn::Base64": {
    "Fn::Join": [
      "",
      [
        "#!/bin/bash",
        "\n",
        "sudo apt-get update\n",
        "sudo apt-get install -y nginx\n",
        "sudo service nginx start\n",
        "\n",
        "cat > /var/www/html/index.html << \"EOF\"\n",
        "<title>CloudFormation</title>\n",
        "<h1>Name</h1><p>This page created entirely by CloudFormation. Author: ",
        {
          "Ref": "Author_name_in_parameter"
        },
        "</p>\n",
        "EOF\n",
        "\n"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```